# nginx 301 rewrite root domain works but files are not being redirected

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect a domain to another url in nginx and it works partially.

It looks like this:

```
location /  {
             rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.some_domain.tld/some_dir/some_file.php permanent;
}
```

It redirects fine the root domain, however if I try to load http://www.my_old_domain.tld/some_file.php it won't do the same. It'll load the page.

Thoughts ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
location /
    return 301 http://newdomain.com/a/b/c.php;
}
```

Comment: Nope. It works if I load "http://www.old-domain.tld". However, if I load "http://www.old-domain.tld/some_file.php" then it won't redirect to the new domain.

Comment: then u probably have other locations that are a better match to this URL, so nginx handles them with the other location block, are both URLs on the same domain ? do you want to only redirect a certain case or all requests?